# Javascript reaction time measure in qualtrics for any key press (not click with mouse)

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm very new to javascript and trying to use it for Qualtrics.

I'm setting up a questionnaire where participants have to fill out an open text box and I would like to measure the reaction time for the first keypress (not the first click with the mouse). From what I've gathered from other queries I copied the following mishmash script.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
  let timeOnLoad = new Date().getTime();
  var that = this;
  Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var choiceID = e.keyCode;
    if (choiceID) {
      let timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - timeOnLoad;
      console.log(timeTaken);
      Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    }
  });
});
```

Obviously, it didn't work. Hence, I'm reaching out to see if someone can help me write a script where the time between the page loading and the first key press (any key on the keyboard) gets logged into the data file.

Thank you!

Comment: How did it not work? What error were you getting? was it just that the click event was also counting? Was your console.log printing anything?

Comment: Minor thing but you can use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date.getTime()` (Doesn't work in IE9, if you mind that)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The issue is that the time of the first key press (in the keyboard) is not logged into qualtrics data file. However, the first mouse click is logged in its timing function.